# What do these Formosat-5 patch images mean - who designed them?

Tags: space-art, insignia, mission-patch

Researching for the question [What does the four-leafed clover on Zuma's (and others') mission patch signify?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/23715/12102) I came across the site http://spacexpatchlist.space/ I can't be sure of the validity of the site, but it seems somewhat believable.

While looking for four-leaved clovers there, I saw these two patches. Both designs include the Sunflower aspect of the Taiwan flag, but also other images that intrigue me.

One has the "all seeing eye" (with a *blue colored iris* no less, and the other has something that looks like R2D2 with tentacles.

What does this imagery represent? Who generates and approves these graphic elements? Is there any further documentation? Theories?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'd guess your R2D2 is a celtic warrior, but no idea what it means.

Comment: 30 SW is the 30th Space Wing which runs the launch facilities at Vandenberg. I'd guess that is their mission (launch ops) patch, not Space X's. 1 ASTS is the 1st Air and Space Test Squadron (a unit of 30 SW), also at V-berg, ditto about the patch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The top patch is made by 30SW 2ROPS, the lower one is made by 30SW 1ASTS. The spacepatchlist.space site is quite authoritative about the patches and details. Source: I maintain it.

You can read about the squadrons here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/30th_Space_Wing

Whenever they launch a rocket and/or payload they'll produce a patch and use the proceeds to fund their philanthropy works, such as the VAFB Thrift Shop.

As for the graphical design, few people are privvy to the designers thoughts, but you can analyze them yourself to get an idea. Formosat-5 is an Earth Observation Satellite for Taiwan’s National Space Organization so the Illuminati type eye and the camera shutter design lean towards observation themes.

Comment: The squadrons are easily found. Try Google.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/30th_Space_Wing

Whenever they launch a rocket and/or payload they'll produce a patch and use the proceeds to fund their philanthropy works, such as the VAFB Thrift Shop. As for the graphical design, few people are privvy to the designers thoughts, but you can analyze them yourself to get an idea.

Comment: This is great, thank you! I'm still wondering about the choice of the "baby blue" all-seeing eye in the upper patch (it's a rare and recessive gene) and the use of the word "lens" in the lower patch, since the imaging is done with a [Cassegrain reflecting telescope which uses a 45 cm diameter *mirror*](https://directory.eoportal.org/web/eoportal/satellite-missions/f/formosat-5) rather than a lens. These are the things that really piqued my interest into who did and who approved the actual layout.

Comment: I think the lettering on the circle in the lower patch is just riffing on the lettering that appears around camera lenses. https://johnlewis.scene7.com/is/image/JohnLewis/235948306?$prod_exlrg$

Comment: @OrganicMarble oh I understand now! I'm being too literal. Oh, the six leaved iris, etc. It's metaphorical!

Comment: @OrganicMarble: FWIW, I just posted [a bug report about that link.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/308033/mathjax-should-not-attempt-to-parse-autolinked-urls)

Comment: @IlmariKaronen good catch! I didn't notice that; time for glasses.